# Async Method is not giving warning CS4014 while calling from differnet Assembly

Tags: c#

When directly calling Async method that is located in the same assembly as the caller, we get the expected CS4014 warning. However, when the method being called from different assembly, no warning is given. In VS2015 AsyncStateMachineAttribute is present in metadata, but does not make compiler to produce warning at all while intellisence shows warning just fine.

```
public class Caller
{
    public Task CallWorkAsync()
    {
        // This call will not generate a compile error
        Class1 c = new Class1(); // from different Assembly
        c.DoWorkAsync();

        // This call will generate a compile error
        var c2 = new InSameAssembly();
        c2.DoWorkAsync();

        return Task.FromResult<bool>(true);
    }
}

public class InSameAssembly
{
    public async Task DoWorkAsync()
    {
        await Task.Yield();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question? If you have a bug to report, then report it to Microsoft.

Comment: If I select the filter as Build+intellisence it show warning on both calls but  if I select BuildOnly it shows warning on one place.Just I want to know why the behavior is like this?